# How to Ensure Contact is in Account

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom entity with a lookup to Contact and another lookup to Account.
What is the best way to make sure that the Account is in the parent Account of the Contact?


I am thinking of letting the user choose only the Contact lookup and auto-populating a read-only Account lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your idea is good, but if you have a lot of contacts, they could be difficult to choose. Another strategy is filter the lookup contact with criteria that has the parent account selected. Take a look at some examples:

- http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/filtered-lookups-in-crm-2011/
- http://crmdm.blogspot.pt/2011/05/lookup-filtering-in-crm-2011-using.html
- http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/02/17/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-filtered-lookups/

With Javascript you could warn the user to first choose the account, or disable the contact until the user chooses an account.

Comment: I would extend that with "cross-filtering" - filter Account by Contact and Contact by Account, so the user can choose whichever is easier first. Maybe they have the Contact's name in their mind, or maybe they don't know how to spell the company name. Or vice versa. Also helps if they can create the child record from either parent since one or other lookup would already be populated. You can run a workflow afterwards to validate this as well, or to auto-fill it for the user.

Comment: Great answer! I have an elegant solution now.